# software for organizing text

Tags: full-text-search, tagging, organization, text-processing

(
I suspect that the question may not belong here as it's about software and not about programing. However, this is my computers community, and I trust you guys to refer me elsewhere if you think it's not appropriate to answer it here. 
)

So,
I'm writing a lot. Text. For myself. Diaries, ideas, insights, observations. It always comes in the form of passages, passage at a time.

Until now I used to write in word documents, organizing them by rough categories divided to different documents, and by chronological order.

I figure out that this is way sub optimal. I can have more, and I do need more.

I'm looking for a software that will allow me to:
1 - tag passages
2 - store date and time automatically (created and edited)
3 - powerful full text search
4 - besides the above, I'd like it to have as much word processing capabilities as possible

Recommendations for a software that have this?

Now, I don't need this to be online. I'm doing this for myself, and don't want it to be published anywhere. I figure out however that many web platforms may have much of what I need, so I don't automatically reject the possibility to use one for my offline needs.

Thanks guys

Gidi

Comment: This belongs on superuser. Voting to move.

Answer (score 2):

You could install wordpress or any other suitable blogging software locally and have your own private blog - let's you write passages as short as you like, you can tag it, categorize it, search it. Keeps track of when it was created and edited. And you can probably add a fair amount of word processing capabilities to it via plugins. And you could put it online when you wanted to.
It's a bit install overhead required (probably XAMP) though.